# How can C++ make it possible to use dynamic container classes even in embedded systems?

Tags: c++, c, memory, embedded-systems

How can C++ make it possible to use dynamic container classes even in embedded systems?

---

Background info:

I've been working with PIC (C) and AVR (C++) processors and at the moment (PIC C) I'm trying to send a text (with undefined length) to a method that only sends this string with a HTTP POST (so it has to know the length beforehand).

---

Problem & question:

On C++ this could easily be achieved with a container class/dynamic array.
Though, when using C, I (guess) I'm continiously overwriting memory addresses (When I use a pointer and then change the length)?

How does C++ (efficiëntly?) manage dynamic arrays? Are all bits off the dynamic array scattered throughout your memory and how does it find these back? Or does it secretly allocate memory/blocks of memory?

Comment: Why do you say "even in embedded systems"? I don't see what that would have to do with anything, unless you don't have access to `malloc`/`realloc` or their C++ equivalents.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't quite sure if the architecture of the device would change anything, thought it'd be good to add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ can do it the same way C does. All C++ gives you is easier-to-use containers that wrap much of the low-level detail.

For example, a string class can (and does) hold a block of memory on the stack for short strings, only allocating a heap buffer for larger ones. This buffer is exactly like a C string buffer, if the string resizes, the string class will resize it in the same way a C programmer would by allocating a new buffer and copying the old data into it, except that possibly the string class will over-allocate the buffer size to allow for future appending to the string. Some string classes will count the length of the string using strlen, others will store the length as a member variable that it keeps up to date.

Arrays are managed in the same way, but there are specialised containers that give you things like linked lists.

Comment: So basically in C++ there are functions that re-locate your memory runtime?

Comment: @FuaZe Yes, but C has functions for that too.

Comment: @Doval I see, but I mean that a C++ string will do this automatically and within C the bound checking/reloallocating is up to you?

Comment: @FuaZe Someone had to write the code in the C++ string implementation to do bound checking and reallocating. Other than syntactic sugar for operators like `+` and automatic conversions from `char *` to `string`, there's no magic going on.

Comment: Thanks for the extra nuancuation! It sometimes looks like Magic though, no, to be honest I was thinking hoe it was implemented also. Didn't think of simply reallocating, haven't done that much runtime allocating (or well I did so, withouth knowing in C++). Was thinking   they might have saved the locations of pieces of storage somewhere. Or pointer to the next piece, but that differs per implementation. Reallocating seems fair, but I know start to see the overhead of soms C++ functions

Comment: The sources for many C++ standard libraries are available. For example the standard library for g++ is available. You can see exactly how the functions are implemented. This is a great way to learn techniques. The sources for Boost libraries are also a good learning tool. There is no magic.

Comment: There isn't much overhead in C++, sometimes it can be much reduced compared to C - eg my string class, trades a little memory for a massive perf game with tiny strings. In addition there are classes such as rope that are for very long strings, where pieces are allocated in chains which can improve performance again if not every piece needs realloc. Pretty much everything you can do in C++ you can do in C, it just takes you a lot longer and wouldn't be very maintainable.